# Function template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11

I ran into the following code that defines a function template in a class:

```
#include <cstdint>

class foo {
public:
    enum class magic_type : std::uint32_t {
        START = 0,
        BLUE = 0xFF000001,
        RED,
    };

    struct header_t {
        uint32_t version;
        magic_type magic;
    };

    template <typename T>
    static bool is_of_type(header_t *h)
    {
        return (h->magic == T::magic_type);
    }

    foo(uint32_t ver, foo::magic_type mag)
    {
        header.version = ver;
        header.magic = mag;
    }

    header_t header;
};
```

I am finding the implementation of 'is_of_type` confusing.  The code as is compiles, so syntactically must be correct.  However, this method is not invoked from any other part of the program, so I am not sure what the intent of the function is (lack of documentation).  I figured there could be two interpretation of the function:

1. Return true/false based on the magic type of an object and the specific enum type passed as the function template parameter.

   E.g. An invocation of the method would be:

   ```
   foo bar(1.2, foo::magic_type::BLUE);
   bool temp = bar.is_of_type<foo::magic_type::BLUE>(&(bar.header));
   ```

   However, in the above case, I am not really passing a type (as in an int, or char, etc).  Right?  The code does not compile.
2. Return true/false if the magic type is a valid enum.

   In this case, I am assuming the function does not need to be templated, and could be re-written as:

   ```
   static bool is_of_type(header_t *h)
   {
       return (h->magic == foo::magic_type);
   }
   ```

   E.g. of an invocation:

   ```
   foo bar(1.2, foo::magic_type::BLUE);
   bool temp = bar.is_of_type(&(bar.header));
   ```

   Again, getting compile error.  I tried using "typename", but my attempts were futile.

Can someone please help me with proper implementation of `is_of_type` for the above two cases and an invocation example.

Comment: Incidentally, why did you write `new foo…` instead of `foo bar(1.2, foo::magic_type::BLUE)`? Hopefully you’re not using such code, with redundant `new`s, in reality.

Comment: @KonradRudolph That was a typo, I was trying out different things to get code to compile.  Thank you pointing it out.  Updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The invocation would be with an explicitly specified type, which has a nested static member called `magic_type`.

For instance, it could be called as follows:

```
struct test {
    static foo::magic_type const magic_type;
};

foo::magic_type const test::magic_type = 42;
```

```
foo bar{1, foo::magic_type::BLUE};
bar.is_of_type<test>(bar.header);
```

The fact that `magic_type` is used twice, once for an `enum class` and once for a static variable, is very confusing though.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.  I personally don't like the names used for the enum and variable, but have to work with code as in.